# Resizing and saving images on a new directory

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am writing a simple function that reads a sequence of images, re-sizes them and then saves each set of re-sized images to a new folder. Here is my code:

```
function [ image ] = FrameResize(Folder, ImgType)

Frames = dir([Folder '/' ImgType]);
NumFrames = size(Frames,1);

new_size = 2;

for i = 1 : NumFrames,
    image = double(imread([Folder '/' Frames(i).name]));

    for j = 2 : 10,
        new_size = power(new_size, j);

        % Creating a new folder called 'Low-Resolution' on the
        % previous directory
        mkdir ('.. Low-Resolution');

        image = imresize(image, [new_size new_size]);
        imwrite(image, 'Low-Resolution');


    end

end

end
```

I have mainly two doubts:

- How can I save those images with specific names, like `im_1_64`, `im_2_64`, etc. according to the iteration and to the resolution?
- How can I make the name of the folder being created change with each iteration so that I save images with the same resolution on the same folder?

Comment: How do you detect resolution?

Comment: Or rather how do you define `Low-Resolution`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the resolution will be: `new_size x new_size`, you can use this in the `imwrite` function:

```
imwrite(image, ['im_' num2str(i) '_' num2str(new_size) '.' ImgType]);
```

Assuming that `ImgType` holds the extension.

To setup the folders you can do something like this:

```
mkdir(num2str(new_size))
cd(num2str(new_size))
imwrite(image, ['im_' num2str(i) '_' num2str(new_size) '.' ImgType]);
cd ..
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. The only remaining problem is that I get a message saying: 'Invalid syntax at num2str. Possibly a),} or ] is missing' at this line:  mkdir ('Low-Resolution Images _' num2str(new_size)), but I can't find what's missing

Comment: If you want to concatenate strings you have to use `strcat('Low-Resolution Images_', num2str(new_size))` or `['Low-Resolution Images_' num2str(new_size)]`

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer you are satisfied with, but I strongly suggest doing two things differently:

- Use `fullfile` to create/concatenate file and path names.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  imread([Folder '/' Frames(i).name])
  ```

  do

  ```
  imread(fullfile(Folder,Frames(i).name))
  ```

  It's good for relative paths too:

  ```
  fullfile('..','Low-Resolution')
  ans =
  ..\Low-Resolution
  ```
- Use `sprintf` to create strings containing numerical data from variables.  Instead of:

  ```
  ['im_' num2str(i) '_' num2str(new_size) '.' ImgType]
  ```

  do

  ```
  sprintf('im_%d_%d.%s', i, new_size, ImgType)
  ```

  You can even specify how many digits you want per integer.  Compare:

  ```
  K>> sprintf('im_%d_%d.%s', i, new_size, ImgType)
  ans =
  im_2_64.png
  K>> sprintf('im_%02d_%d.%s', i, new_size, ImgType)
  ans =
  im_02_64.png
  ```